# Binary Entropy solving over uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, entropy, multisets

Compute the Binary Entropy for X is uniform over the set {1, 2, 3, . . . , 80}

$$H(X) = -\sum_{i=0}^n p(x)log _2p(x) $$

I am pretty confused on this topic if someone could explain an easy way to solve this.

I know their probabilities are 1/n so in this case it will be 1/80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
H(X) = - \sum_{i=1}^{80} \frac{1}{80} \log_2\frac{1}{80} = - 80 \frac{1}{80} \log_2\frac{1}{80} = - \log_2 \frac{1}{80} = \log_2 80
$$

Note that this actually maximises the entropy, the uniform distribution has this property.

Comment: Hey could you example how you the sumation of I=1 to 80 reduced to -80 ?

Comment: @Xzarida you are summing from 1 to 80, so there are 80 terms in the summation, and each of the terms is $1/p_i log_2 p_i = 1/80 log_2 1/80$. So the summation is just $- (1/80 log_2 1/80 + 1/80 log_2 1/80 + \dots + 1/80 log_2 1/80)$, or equivalently.. $- 80 * 1/80 log_2 1/80$